# How to define a keyword as a new test case

Tags: robotframework

I'm currently developing a couple of test cases with robotframework to compare some excel value with value inside our database.

I have to do it inside a specific test case as it is deploy on zephyr.
I am checking each value inside this test case by calling a homemade Keyword that does :

```
Run Keyword    Should Contain    ${valeurExcel1}    ${valeurBDD1}

Run Keyword Should Contain ${valeurExcel2} ${valeurBDD2}
```

etc...

I need every single one of those "Should Contain" to be display in a separated row in the report.html

It currently only appear as one row as it is one test case.

Is there anyway to specify to robot framework that i want him to consider every "Should Contain" as a unique test case and to display it in a row on the report.html ?
(Maybe by tagging ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. If you want a row for each "should contain" then each of those call should be made in its own test case.

But I think the problem lies in your "I have to do it inside a specific test case as it is deploy on zephyr". Whatever you need to do before/after a test case, can be done in a ["suite setup"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) (and ["suite teardown"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown)). So you could have this kind of architecture:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  deploy SUT / Zephyr
Suite Teardown  shutdown SUT / Zephyr

*** Test Cases ***
tc1
    Run Keyword Should Contain ${valeurExcel1} ${valeurBDD1}

tc2  
    Run Keyword Should Contain ${valeurExcel2} ${valeurBDD2}
```

Comment: Thank uou Laurent, I managed to put values inside Suite variable and compare them inside other test cases ! Have a great day !